# c++ eigen svd sum to float

Tags: c++, eigen

I am calculating bdcsvd of a matrix and then calculating the sum of singularvalues like so

```
std::stringstream ss(mat_str);
int m = 66;
int n = 66;
MatrixXd A(m,n);
for(int i=0; i<m; ++i)
  for(int j=0; j<n; ++j)
    ss >> A(i,j);

Eigen::BDCSVD<MatrixXd> svd(A,ComputeFullU|ComputeFullV);
auto sum = svd.singularValues().colwise().sum().cast<float>();
cout << "Here is the type of :" << endl << typeid(sum).name() << endl;
```

The type of sum shows `N5Eigen12CwiseUnaryOpINS_8internal14scalar_cast_opIdfEEKNS_16PartialReduxExprIKNS_6MatrixIdLin1ELi1ELi0ELin1ELi1EEENS1_10member_sumIdEELi0EEEEE` instead of float . How do i convert/cast sum to float?

Comment: a) Don't use `auto`. b) Because of the `colwise` you have a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: Eigen makes heavy use of expression templates in a way that does not play well with `auto`. So try to avoid using auto when dealing with operations on Eigen types.

Comment: @AviGinsburg: thanx for the indication abt vector and not scalar ... qs abt not using auto .... if not to use auto what is the type .. i tried using VectorXd , but get error `error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY`

Comment: The error was quite explicit. You tried to use `VectorXd` (a double vector) but you used `cast<float>()` (a float vector).

Comment: @AviGinsburg: Agreed ... typo on my end .... thanx both your comments helped ... upvoted both the comments